# How Does Applications know which Internet Data is theirs?

Tags: operating-system

This Morning I Booted my Computer and Had multiple applications needing an update. While I was waiting for the applications to update, a question came to mind which I thought I'd ask in here.

The question is How does each application known which internet data being retrieved is theirs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The applications don't even care about it, they let the Kernel sort out that information.

When an application establishes a connection with a remote computer, the Kernel assigns that application a local port, which is a number among 0-65535. This port on the receiving end can either be requested by the application or the kernel will assign a random port. Generally there is only one application per port, however it is possible for multiple applications to receive the same data, though this is rare.

When a packet is received by the network interface, the kernel will sort the packet by its destination port. There will be a table in the kernel mapping ports to processes, and each application will receive the relevant data without caring about any other possible data that could be coming in the computer.

If you are a programmer, you can learn about all this stuff by reading about socket programming:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_socket

is a good place to start. You can also google "socket programming" with your preferred programming language to get an idea of how this is set up on the programming end.