# How does OS know which application to send network data to without a port number (i.e. non UDP/TCP data)

Tags: networking

A previous similar questions have been asked before:

- [How Does Applications know which Internet Data is theirs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21399315/how-does-applications-know-which-internet-data-is-theirs)

The basic answer given is that it uses the port number.

But the port number is on the TCP/UDP frame. If I send a packet using non TCP/UDP (e.g ICMP/ping, Profinet, EtherCAT), how does that get routed to the right application?

I understand well known data formats would have their own routing (I expect ICMP to route based on maybe sequence number or src/dst address), but what about a custom/unknown [EtherType](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EtherType)/[protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_IP_protocol_numbers)? Does the OS just reject the packet, or send it to every application? Does every EtherType/protocol need to have a "driver" installed?